# how to color a portion of a cell in aspxgrid?

Tags: .net, devexpress

In my aspxgrid i have created all columns dynamically, so i have a cell contains three status in three lines.e.g.

```
Item Status    Date
               1st 2nd . .... ...
     Booked     2   4  5 1 2 4........
 1   Available  1   1  1 1 1 1........
     Not Avail  0   0  0 0 0 0........
```

so these cell are for 1 row . I have used customcolumndisplaytext event to do so. Now i want to give different color for three status rows. Can u guys help me with it please ? I need to do this ,there are several items and for each item i have three status.
Is there any different approach to do so please enlighten me.

Thanks,
Mriganka

Comment: You should post this question on the DevExpress site (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question). They will be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: already posted.Nothing till now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [GridViewDataColumn.DataItemTemplate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewDataColumn_DataItemTemplatetopic) combined with simple html elements and to achieve this. Also, take a look at [DataItemTemplate demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Templates/Template.aspx).

For simpler solution, set `e.DisplayText` in CustomColumnDisplayText to html.

Here is example of `CustomColumnDisplayText` event handler that alternates word colors inside cell:

```cs
protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if ("job_desc".Equals(e.Column.FieldName))
    {
        e.DisplayText = "";
        string[] tokens = ((string)e.Value).Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                e.DisplayText += "<span style='color:red'>" + tokens[i] + @"</span>";
            }
            else
            {
                e.DisplayText += "<span  style='color:blue'>" + tokens[i] + @"</span>";
            }
            e.DisplayText += " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but on each row i have to set 3 colors for 3 statuses, so how to do that, im still in dark..

Comment: So, this will work on a particular cell right..but in my case i have three lines inside one cell ,now ive to color three lines with red,green and blue inside one cell.

Comment: I understood that you fill those statuses into e.DisplayText inside CustomColumnDisplayText event handler? Just wrap each status in separate html element of your choice (span, p, ...) and color it according to your needs using style attribute.

Comment: Ok, so it does fill the background of the text, but it does not filling the whole cell, its only filling text background ,that causes horrible gridview design. Thanks for your guide anyway @Filip.

Comment: Thank you so much Filip.It works with forecolor ,i needed to do backcolor. Anyway it works.